# Как переопределить класс внутри другого класса на java

Tags: java, классы, объекты

Есть public class Document.
Внутри класса используется другой класс - FieldsReports

```
@JsonProperty("fields")
private FieldsReports fields;
```

Таких классов есть несколько с разными значениями:

1. FieldsReports1
2. FieldsReports2
3. FieldsReports3

   Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне при вызове класса Document задать, чтобы в  Document использовался конретный класс (FieldsReports2 например) по какому то значению например при вызове, можно так сделать?

Comment: В общем решила наследованием, т.е. создается класс Fields, добавляется в class Document.
От Fields наследуются: 
FieldsReports1, 
FieldsReports2, 
FieldsReports3.
А потом в методах используются уже наследники. В принципе устраивает пока

Comment: Наследовать не обязательно, можете определить интерфейс с общими методами для всех классов либо выделить нужный интерфейс из этих классов.